# .net sdk AWS dynamoDB order by descending with QueryRequest or ScanRequest?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I try with `ScanRequest` but I see any post talk about that I have to use `QueryRequest`.
But I make tests and don´t work.

How I can get all register and order descending by date?

```cs
var request = new QueryRequest
{
    TableName = "SuaTabelaDynamoDB",
    KeyConditionExpression = "#partitionKey = :partitionKeyValue",
    ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"#partitionKey", "SuaChaveDePartição"}
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
    {
        {":partitionKeyValue", new AttributeValue { S = "ValorDaChaveDePartição" }}
    },
    ScanIndexForward = false  // Define false to order descending
};
```

I receive the error:

> Query condition missed key schema element: id

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the exception

> Query condition missed key schema element: id

because you specified your partition key to be `SuaChaveDePartição` when the actually partition key is `id`.

[Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) expects you to define at least the partition key in order to make a request, it's mandatory. You can optionally specify conditions on the sort key, or use a FilterExpression on any non-key attributes.

---

As for scanning in reverse order, that is not possible. Scan always reads from the start to the end of the data, and the data return is grouped by partition key, and ordered by sort key. Keep in mind the entire data set is not ordered, just the groups of partition keys (item collections).

Comment: my problem is: how can get all itens on dynamoDB ordened or only filter date >= <= and ordened? for example on SQL ""select * from clients where createDate >= "2023-12-01" and createDate <= "2024-01-30" orderby createDate desc"

Comment: i think that is not possible, because queryRequest have a "KeyConditionExpression" and this is only term equals - "#partitionKey = :partitionKeyValue" it´s ok - but "#partitionKey >= :partitionKeyValue" it is not possible.